# Is there built-in feature in C# for string for tracking character-level metadata (tags)?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, stringbuilder

Is there some class in C# that would behave like string and will allow me to store custom metadata (tags) for some characters/words?

For example, for a string `Example  string` I might want to add information that capital letter `E` is *capital letter* and I might want to add type of some letters (say *vocals*).Then I might want to call `.Replace` or `.Trim` on the string and I need the result should still contain 'tags' for unchanged letters in the sequence.

Is something like that possible in C#/.NET without having to write all the logic myself?

Comment: No, there is no class that would do all of that built-in.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud So are there some classes that would help me build it?

Comment: Of course, you can build effectively anything, but you're going to have to write all of the logic surrounding what a tag is, how replacement works, and how you define the meta-data (i.e. `E` is a *capital letter*)

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud that is what I was afraid of :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to "is there anything **built-in**" is no.

However, you can create your own class to deal with whatever metadata info structure you want and expose the `string` value as an inner property. You also can use it to override the `ToString()` method. This way you'll be able to pass around your object and still work with its `string` equivalent.

By overloading operators you'll also be able to do casting and comparisons with regular `string` instances.

Comment: +1 thanks for confirmation of what I was afraid of. I know all of these the problem is that I will have to code my own efficient regex, trimming etc. logic in my class. That might be nightmare...

Answer (score 1):

**just for the fun of it!**

to run this quickly:

1. Download the always amazing [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/)
2. Open it and select `Language C# Program`
3. paste the code below
4. press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>

---

```
void Main()
{
    string str = "Example, string";
    var output = Explain(str);

    OutputExplanation(output);
}

private void OutputExplanation(List<LetterExplanation> input)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach(var ltr in input)
        sb.AppendFormat("The letter {0} is {1}\n", ltr.Letter, ltr.Type);

    sb.ToString().Dump();
}

private List<LetterExplanation> Explain(string input) 
{
    var sb = new List<LetterExplanation>();

    foreach(char c in input.ToCharArray())
    {
        //c.Dump(); 
        LetterType type = LetterType.Character;

        // vowel, consonant or special
        if("aeiou".IndexOf(c.ToString(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
            type |= LetterType.Vowel;
        else if(" ,.-_<>/\\".IndexOf(c.ToString(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
            type |= LetterType.Special;
        else
            type |= LetterType.Consonant;

        // uppercase or lowercase
        if(char.IsUpper(c) && (type & LetterType.Special) != LetterType.Special)
            type |= LetterType.Uppercase;
        else if((type & LetterType.Special) != LetterType.Special)
            type |= LetterType.Lowercase;

        // add
        sb.Add(new LetterExplanation() { Letter = c, Type = type });
    }

    return sb;
} 

[Flags]
public enum LetterType {
    Vowel = 1, Consonant = 1 << 1, Uppercase = 1 << 2, Lowercase = 1 << 3, Number = 1 << 4, Special = 1 << 5, Character = 1 << 6
}

public class LetterExplanation
{
    public char Letter { get; set; }
    public LetterType Type { get; set; }
}
```

you will have an output of:

```
The letter E is Vowel, Uppercase, Character
The letter x is Consonant, Lowercase, Character
The letter a is Vowel, Lowercase, Character
The letter m is Consonant, Lowercase, Character
The letter p is Consonant, Lowercase, Character
The letter l is Consonant, Lowercase, Character
The letter e is Vowel, Lowercase, Character
The letter , is Special, Character
The letter   is Special, Character
The letter s is Consonant, Lowercase, Character
The letter t is Consonant, Lowercase, Character
The letter r is Consonant, Lowercase, Character
The letter i is Vowel, Lowercase, Character
The letter n is Consonant, Lowercase, Character
The letter g is Consonant, Lowercase, Character
```

---

[image]